# Wait for asynchronous call to finish

Tags: ios, swift

At load time of viewcontroller I am disabling several elements. Thereafter the view controller is making an AFNetworking POST. Depending on the result, control needs to change the state of the controller. But according to the code below, I am unable to handle the thing.

//Controller code that call the class method for the network call

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        btnNext.hidden = true;
        txtEmail.enabled = false;
        if APISFAuthentication.sfAuthenticateGuest() {

            btnNext.hidden = false
            txtEmail.enabled = true
            vProgressIndicator.hidden = true
        }


    }
```

// Class definition as below

```
import Foundation

class APISFAuthentication {


  init(x: Float, y: Float) {

  }

  static func sfAuthenticateGuest() -> Bool {

    var isConneced = false
    let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()
    let postData = ["grant_type":"password","client_id":APISessionInfo.SF_CLIENT_ID,"client_secret":APISessionInfo.SF_CLIENT_SECRET,"username":APISessionInfo.SF_GUEST_USER,"password":APISessionInfo.SF_GUEST_USER_PASSWORD]

    manager.POST(APISessionInfo.SF_APP_URL,
        parameters: postData,
        success: { (operation, responseObject) in
            print("JSON: " + responseObject.description)
            isConneced = true
        },
        failure: { (operation, error) in
            print("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)

    })
    return isConneced
  }

  static func sfAuthenticateUser(userEmail: String,userPassword: String) -> Bool {


    let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()
    let postData = ["grant_type":"password","client_id":APISessionInfo.SF_CLIENT_ID,"client_secret":APISessionInfo.SF_CLIENT_SECRET,"username":APISessionInfo.SF_GUEST_USER,"password":APISessionInfo.SF_GUEST_USER_PASSWORD]

    manager.POST(APISessionInfo.SF_APP_URL,
        parameters: postData,
        success: { (operation, responseObject) in
            print("JSON: " + responseObject.description)
        },
        failure: { (operation, error) in
            print("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)

    })
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Use a completion block that gets called when the connection is established. As long as the request is running disable some dependant parts of the UI or show a loading icon or whatever.

Comment: @luk2302 is exactly right- you just want to disable user interaction while the asynchronous call is happening. An easy thing to do is present a UIAlertController that says "loading" or whatever and then dismiss it upon completion,